# How can I correctly implement my test method to test variables for my class?

Tags: java, testing, interface, comparator, deque

I have a class `Palindrome` that has two methods, one method `public Deque<Character> wordToDeque(String word)` that turns a string into a Deque and another one, `public boolean isPalindrome(String word)` that takes in a string, turns it into a Deque, and sees if the string is a Palindrome or not. Here is my code for Palindrome class:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Palindrome {
    public Deque<Character> wordToDeque(String word) {
        Deque<Character> L = new LinkedListDeque<>();
        for (int x = 0; x < word.length()-1; x++) {
             L.add(word.charAt(x));
        }
        return L;
    }
    public boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
        Deque<Character> L = new LinkedListDeque<>();

        for (int x = 0; x < word.length()-1; x++) {
            L.add(word.charAt(x));
        }
        Iterator<Character> A = L.descendingIterator();
        Iterator<Character> B = L.iterator();
        while (A.hasNext() && B.hasNext()) {
        if (Objects.equals(A,B)) {
            return true;
        } else {return false;}
    }
        return false;
```

Now. based on this, I'm trying to test some few cases from another class `TestPalindrome` which contains some test cases for the Palindrome class.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
 

public class TestPalindrome {
    // You must use this palindrome, and not instantiate
    // new Palindromes, or the autograder might be upset.
    static Palindrome palindrome = new Palindrome();

    @Test
    public void testWordToDeque() {
        Deque<Character> d = palindrome.wordToDeque("persiflage");
        String actual = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < "persiflage".length(); i++) {
            actual += d.removeFirst();
        }
        assertEquals("persiflage", actual);
    }
}
*/
```

However, my TestPalindrome class doesn't seem to be able to run due to an error in the implementation of Deque in  `Deque<Character> d = palindrome.wordToDeque("persiflage");`. I'm trying to find what's gone wrong but I can't seem to debug it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error message reads:

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'java.util.Deque<java.lang.Character>', required: 'Deque<java.lang.Character>'
Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'void'
```

P.S. Here are some few extra interfaces that I have used in my code, in case it may be helpful in debugging.

Interface Deque:

```
Interface Deque<T> {
    void addFirst(T items);
    void addLast(T items);
    String toString();
    void removeLast();
    void removeFirst();
    void get(int index);
    int size();
    boolean isEmpty();
}
```

Interface CharacterComparator:

```
public interface CharacterComparator<T>{
    boolean equalChars(char x, char y);
}
```

Comment: You have your own Deque interface, but are importing java. util.Deque

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting with the **Operator '+'** is due to the fact that your `removeFirst()` operation from the `Deque<T>` interface returns `void`, meaning that when you execute the following line on your `testWordToDeque()` method, it will produce the error you specified:

```java
actual += d.removeFirst();
```

To solve this, you should change the return type of the `removeFirst()` to `T`, and the type you choose, should override the `toString()` method, in this case, the `Character` class.

Also, the operations `removeLast()` and `get()` from the same interface, shouldn't be void as well..

If you don't want your "remove" operations to return a value, keep it `void`, and use another method, such as the `get()`, once you've changed the return type.

Comment: The return type should be T, not String